# objects not showing up in render 2.9

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, 2d

I have a render scene in blender that is meant to look like this:
[image]

however the render looks like this (its abit hard to see but the only thing in that image is the stickman drawring and the background is transparent?:
[image]

However its not transparent in the world film options so I have no idea what has happened. I had a similar issue like this in my younger blender days of 2.79 however you cant do "W" "clear all restrict render" anymore... Please help. Also the visibility in the layer settings is all set so it should be seen in render...

Also if you still cant see the stickman this may help you (youll need to enlargen the image potentially to see it and the background has that transparent checker texture as well. Also the compositing has nothing to do with it.:
[image]

Comment: Related as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215459/eevee-render-output-is-black-but-it-appears-in-cycles-what-i-did-incorrectly-d/215467#215467

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I've overlooked which version of Blender you're using. I'll leave the answer here in case any of it still applies.

[image]

You haven't accidentally clicked on those camera icons in the Outliner, and made the objects unrenderable?  If so, click again on the camera icon.

Or made the lights unrenderable? If so, click again on the camera icon. Another possibility with lighting is the lamps could be too far away. Or they could be in another layer to the objects and you might have accidentally clicked "this layer only" on the lights.

Or put materials on the objects while in Blender Render, and then tried to render in Cycles?  If so, stick to Blender Render, or assign materials in Cycles if you want to render in that.